# Power BI how to pass a null as a text in a function in FetchXml

Tags: powerbi, dynamics-crm, odata, fetchxml, auditing

I have a FetchXml query for returning dynamics crm data that I have generated using XrmToolbox with Power Query (M) Builder.

The data is more than 5000 records and creates an invoked function to set the page 'x' and the paging cookie 'z'.

Somewhere I have read to set paging-cookie value z as null, however it is a text value in the function.

GetResults = (z as text, x as number) =>
....<fetch distinct=""False"" page=""" & Text.From(x) & """ paging-cookie=""" & z & """>

I haven't been able to get it to work as it errors at record row 501.

Maybe I'm doing this all wrong, please can someone show the steps to do this task.

I have tried " " and "", and a single space but it errors with the follow:

ExpressionError: We cannot convert a value of type Table to type Function.
Details:
Value=[Table]
Type:=[Type]

Comment: my tool Dataverse REST Builder (https://github.com/GuidoPreite/DRB) can generate M query for the Retrieve Multiple request. It uses OData instead of FetchXML and supports the retrieval of 5000+ records. If you have time you can try to use it

Comment: Thank you Guido your tool is amazing.  Thank you for helping me with this issue, it has helped so much. Thank you for producing this tool.